# Login options in SEDE do not work

Tags: support, data-explorer

Clicking the login options such as Yahoo in https://data.stackexchange.com/account/login?returnurl=/account/login?returnurl=/account/login?returnurl=/stackoverflow/queries  doesn't work. Hovering mouse over the login options show the same URL https://data.stackexchange.com/account/login?returnurl=/account/login?returnurl=/stackoverflow/queries#.

Is it because I am under the [GFW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Firewall)?

Comment: If I click on Wordpress or Bloggar I have to provide a username first and then it shows me an error: *No OpenID endpoint found.*. Is that the same for you? Do you have an Yahoo account?

Comment: all the login options are linked to https://data.stackexchange.com/account/login?returnurl=/account/login?returnurl=/stackoverflow/queries#.

Comment: Yes it's because of the Firewall, JS is blocked on your side so you can't use most SE features. When clicking the login options, you should get textbox and asked to put the proper username or URL, depends what you click. It's done with JavaScript, which is blocked on your side. Unlike SE sites, SEDE does not have any "rollback" to alternative source, so I'm afraid you can't use SEDE.

Comment: @rene not relevant, you probably missed the OP last paragraph.

Comment: @ShadowWizardChasingStars by "JS is blocked on your side", do you mean all javascript codes are blocked or just some? I can still access a lot of websites which I believe to use javascript code.

Comment: Not all JS codes, those hosted on Google. Sites that don't use Google to host their JS might have their JS working.