# How can I find my OpenID identifier for logging in to SEDE?

Tags: support, data-explorer, openid

In [my previous post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/386621/login-options-in-sede-do-not-work), all the login options at SEDE seem to be linked to the same URL which doesn't work. The last one I haven't tried is OpenID. But how can I find it?

Comment: You can't "find" such thing. You have to find OpenID provider and create account there, then you should have URL to put in the textbox. SE itself used to be one, but they removed it long years ago due to not giving any profit and costing too much to maintain. (Fair to add, many companies stopped being OpenID providers for same reason, including big ones)

Comment: "due to not giving any profit and costing too much to maintain" - that's a very cynical and unfair revision / wording of reality

Comment: @Rob by all means, I'm open to hear the real reasoning.

Comment: You can run your own OpenId server, for example https://github.com/ory/hydra and then provide in SEDE the url to your OpenId server and that should still bring you to your server where you can authenticate

Comment: Related: *[OpenID endpoints and URL will be removed on 2022-11-01](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/381456/openid-endpoints-and-url-will-be-removed-on-november-1-2022)*